# Pass xml config file into javascript library via require.js?

Tags: javascript, parameters, path, requirejs

I've received a third party javascript library from a vendor with integration instructions that say use the following script include:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="../Scripts/thirdpartyscript.js?config.xml"></script>
```

Note the "?config.xml" bit at the end of the src tag.  It's an xml file containing data that the library parses and acts on.  Removing the parameter causes the library to throw an exception as it tries to parse a null xml response object.

Require.js doesn't want the "?config.xml" parameter at the end.  It treats it like it's part of the lib file name.

Rewiring the third party code won't be a manageable option.  Can't remove the code as it's an integral component of the system.  I don't want to dump require.js as the app is SPA backbone and require.js is module/dependency manager for the entire backbone code base.

Any viable options?

**REVISED ORIGINAL POST FOR CLARITY:**

Comment: It would be useful to show what config you've tried to get RequireJS to load the script.

Answer (score 0):

You may be misunderstanding how the "src" attribute of the script tag works.  All it does is include the script from the URL given.  If the web server serving the file does nothing with the query string (?config.xml), it is just ignored.  Remember, "script" tags just include code in your page and executes the loaded code, THAT IS IT.  The script tag wouldn't even understand what you mean by "?config.xml" beyond that it is just part of the URL, and just loads scripts from the URL you provide it.

What you possibly need to do is include the script file and call some function or object/function in that script with the XML file as a parameter.  The script can, perhaps, retrieve that XML file from the web server (via ajax, a library like jQuery can help with that) also and then process that XML.  However, the process of doing that may be out of the scope of what my answer can provide without writing a small "novella" :)

Short Answer:  The "?config.xml", as far as the script that is loaded goes, does nothing.

Comment: Appreciate you taking the time to respond.

Comment: Appreciate you taking the time to respond.  Let me clarify with additional detail.  The"?config.xml" definitely does something.  The library I'm including is a third party product from Akamai.  I am not at liberty to rework how they configure their software.  I've spoken to them and not supplying the "?config.xml" parameter in the src include breaks their code.  A javascript exception occurs as it begins to parse a null xml request object.  I've verified here by removing and replacing the parameter.  So somehow I need to include this parameter.  I can do it in a regular script tag and it works

Comment: I see.  Then do have .xml files that you configure on Akamai that Akami uses in their scripts then?  I have a feeling that they process the XML file and generate a custom JavaScript file on-demand on *their* servers.

Comment: OK NOW I SEE THE problem... require JS is causing the issue - i feel totally derpy :)  Sorry about that!

Comment: Not a problem.  Appreciate any response.  As of now I have no require.js fix for this.  Akamai did respond with a manual load option for the data that eliminates the need for the query string parameter.  So I've worked around, but the issue of a query string param for require.js users would still be open.  Not sure if I should close this question or not?  Would anyone else need?  Not sure.

Comment: I wonder if this is an issue to bring up with the require.js developers/community?